# CSS keyframe not moving completely off the screen despite 100% translate tx set to -100%

Tags: jquery, css

```js
// Sample items to add to the news-ticker
let sampleNewsItems = [
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
  "Vivamus enim magna, elementum in consectetur sit amet, porta ut eros"
];

// Iterate through the sample news items and process accordingly
let nextTimeoutDur;
for (let x = 0; x < sampleNewsItems.length; x++) {
  let screenWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
  $('.ticker-wrap').width(screenWidth);

  $(".ticker-wrap").append('<div class="ticker-item" data-index="' + x + '"><span class="tickerContent"></span></div>');
  $('.ticker-item[data-index="' + x + '"] .tickerContent').html(sampleNewsItems[x]);

  let newsItemLength = 500;
  $('.ticker-item[data-index="' + (x - 1) + '"]').outerWidth(500);

  let tickerDur = 7;
  nextTimeoutDur = x > 0 ? (tickerDur * newsItemLength) / screenWidth : 0;

  $(".ticker-item[data-index=" + x + "]").css("animation", "ticker " + tickerDur + "s  linear " + nextTimeoutDur + "s  infinite");
}
```

```css
@keyframes ticker {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(100vw, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

.ticker-wrap {
  width: 100%;
}

.ticker-wrap .ticker-item {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ticker-wrap"></div>
```

I would like to have the second ticker item completely off the viewport before it disappears, which is why I set `transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);` for 100% of the keyframe. However the second ticker item disappears from viewport as soon as the first one is gone. Why is this so? And how can I fix it?

[Here is a CodePen with my code.](https://codepen.io/prizzi13/pen/JwGmGE)

https://codepen.io/prizzi13/pen/JwGmGE

Comment: Not really clear what you are after, and you don't need any JS for this, as far as I can see.

Comment: @VXp I think it might be clearer if you look at the CodePen. What I'm trying to achieve is a single line ticker, and not the multiple line ticker as it renders in the stackoverflow code snippet. The entire single line ticker needs to scroll past the left side of the view port.

Answer (score 0):

`position` of `.ticker-item` should be `absolute`